# Laravel 4 - API Endpoint returns no response

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm building a REST API using Laravel 4, and I am having an issue.  When I try to send a request to the API in Postman, it will send back errors such as 405, but it simply won't respond to the POST request, which it is designated for.  Postman simply says that the server didn't respond.  I have tried everything, including changing the code of the controller method to return a plain old 200 code.  But, that didn't work either.  There is too much code for me to post, but if anyone has any solutions, please let me know.  (Btw all other endpoints can be accessed just fine)

My route definition:

```
Route::group(array(

    'name' => 'social-conversation'
), function() {

    Route::group(array(

        'before' => 'auth'
    ), function() {

    Route::post('social/conversation/create', array(

        'as'    => 'social-conversation-create',
        'uses'  => 'Social_ConversationController@createx'
    ));

    Route::put('social/conversation/{id}/update', array(

        'as'    => 'social-conversation-update',
        'uses'  => 'Social_ConversationController@update'
    ));

    Route::delete('social/conversation/{id}/delete', array(

        'as'    => 'social-conversation-delete',
        'uses'  => 'Social_ConversationController@delete'
    ));
});
});
```

My controller definition:

```
class Social_ConversationController extends BaseController {

public function create() { /* Code goes here */ }
```

Comment: Have you checked your route definitions to ensure that they support POST requests? Please edit your question to include the route and URL that you used.

Comment: I added them into the post.  Check them out

Comment: Hi Alex - please post all your `social/conversation` routes. I'm making an educated guess that the problem is the order of your routes. You probably have a `post::social/conversation/{user}` or something similar above the `create` route, so your `create` route is never run.

Comment: The code formatting on here isn't the greatest, but I added it above

Comment: Is the function in your controller `createx()` or `create()`?

Comment: It is create.  I was changing the values earlier trying to see if other functions worked

Comment: I cant see any obvious reason for the problem. What I would do is start 'stripping' your routes, and get it down to a single route that works, then rebuild it slowly and see when the error occurs.

Comment: I checked my controller function for a missing if statement, and I came up with none.  I think it could possible be a framework bug.

Comment: A missing "if" statement? What does that have to do with anything? It is not a framework bug - it is somewhere in your code.